# Why does FactoryBoy create a new object from SubFactory despite FACTORY_DJANGO_GET_OR_CREATE

Tags: django, unit-testing, factory-boy

I have just started using [factory boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orms.html) with Django. It has a setting `FACTORY_DJANGO_GET_OR_CREATE` that means it won't create a new object if one already exists. But when I ask for an existing object with an existing `SubFactory` object, it creates an unused object despite this setting.

For example, in a brand new project, I tried:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

And

```
# factories.py
import factory

from . import models

class AFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = models.A
    FACTORY_DJANGO_GET_OR_CREATE = ('name',)

    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'A-{0}'.format(n))

class BFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = models.B
    FACTORY_DJANGO_GET_OR_CREATE = ('name',)

    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'B-{0}'.format(n))
    a = factory.SubFactory(AFactory)
```

Now:

```
from factories import *

a = AFactory(name="Apple")
models.A.objects.all()
# one object
b = BFactory(a__name="Apple", name="Beetle")
models.B.objects.all()
models.A.objects.all()
# one A object, one B object
b = BFactory(name="Beetle")
models.B.objects.all()
models.A.objects.all()
# still one B object, but now a new, unused A object too
```

Then the final call to `BFactory` has brought into being a new object of class `A`, even though the `B` object with name Beetle already exists (and is not re-created). Why, and how do I stop this new A object being created?

(I know I can get around this by calling instead:

```
b = BFactory(name="Beetle", a__name="Apple")
```

but in my actual use case, I have several dependencies and levels of hierarchy, and it's messy to supply extra redundant parameters this way - and I can't seem to get the right combination of parameters.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above is a problem when I also have a class C that has a foreign key to B.  When I created a new `CFactory` object like so:

```
c = CFactory(name="Cat", b__name="Beetle")
```

it also creates a new unused `A` object.

I have found the solution to this is simple: instead, make the new `CFactory` object like this:

```
c = CFactory(name="Cat", b=b)
```

where `b` is either a `B` object or a `BFactory` object.

Answer (score 1):

You could call use:

```
a = SubFactory(AFactory, name='Reuse this model A instance')
```

That way the following two invocations are equal:

```
BFactory()
BFactory(a__name='Reuse this model A instance')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the subfactory kicks in after the get_or_create irrespectively.

Not sure of a s9lution though, it's not a use case I've come across. IMHO fixtures that depend on get_or_create have too much potential for magic. The alternative (always create) can be a little more tedious if you have a complicated test case, but is safer

Comment: Thanks! Say A is a user and B is a post. With the code above, if I create a new post, it always creates a new user and associates the post with that new user. Can I use `factory boy` to test one user with several posts?

Comment: I realised my comment is unclear - one user with several posts is easy if you set `FACTORY_DJANGO_GET_OR_CREATE` as I do above. But I actually have users owning businesses, and the businesses make the posts (i.e. there's a third class C). In fact there can be other objects with `ForeignKeys` to the posts too (classes D, E...). So every time I create one of these downstream objects, I get a whole hierarchy of newly created (and unused) objects. That's what I'd like to avoid.